# Difference between "->" and "->>" in Clojure

Tags: macros, clojure

What's difference between macros `->` and `->>`:

```
user> (macroexpand-1 '(->> 1 a b c))
;; => (c (b (a 1)))
user> (macroexpand-1 '(-> 1 a b c))
;; => (c (b (a 1)))
```

Let's see source code:

```
user> (clojure.repl/source ->)
(defmacro ->
  "Threads the expr through the forms. Inserts x as the
  second item in the first form, making a list of it if it is not a
  list already. If there are more forms, inserts the first form as the
  second item in second form, etc."
  {:added "1.0"}
  [x & forms]
  (loop [x x, forms forms]
    (if forms
      (let [form (first forms)
            threaded (if (seq? form)
                       (with-meta `(~(first form) ~x ~@(next form))
                                   (meta form))
                       (list form x))]
        (recur threaded (next forms)))
      x)))
;; => nil

user> (clojure.repl/source ->>)
(defmacro ->>
  "Threads the expr through the forms. Inserts x as the
  last item in the first form, making a list of it if it is not a
  list already. If there are more forms, inserts the first form as the
  last item in second form, etc."
  {:added "1.1"}
  [x & forms]
  (loop [x x, forms forms]
    (if forms
      (let [form (first forms)
            threaded (if (seq? form)
                       (with-meta `(~(first form) ~@(next form) ~x)
                                   (meta form))
                       (list form x))]
        (recur threaded (next forms)))
      x)))
;; => nil
```

(Indentation is mine.)

So, `->` is older, but they look pretty the same... Any reason for duplication?

Comment: Read the descriptions. `->` inserts things as the **second** item in each form, `->>` inserts things as the **last** item in each form. If the forms start out with only one item, then they're equivalent.

Comment: And in the code, `(~(first form) ~x ~@(next form))` is not the same as `(~(first form) ~@(next form) ~x)` since `~x` is in a different place (2nd versus last).

Comment: @Barmar, my bad, I've been inattentive.

Comment: ClojureDocs often helps with examples as well as explanation and code: look at [->](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E) and [->>](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E%3E).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two macros are different when dealing with threaded forms that take further arguments. Try these for size:

```
(macroexpand '(->> 1 (a b) (c d e) (f g h i)))
(macroexpand '(-> 1 (a b) (c d e) (f g h i)))
```

Comment: Better with `clojure.walk/macroexpand-all`, perhaps.